# How to resolve redis install error

Tags: redis

I want to install redis on aix 6.1, but some problem happened and I can't find the solution to resolve this problem. Who can tell me the reason for this compiler error.

```
# /opt/freeware/bin/make
cd src && /opt/freeware/bin/make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/software/redis-2.8.17/src'
    CC adlist.o
/bin/sh: cc:  not found.
make[1]: *** [adlist.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/software/redis-2.8.17/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to compile Redis without a C compiler (that's what `cc` is) installed or present on your `$PATH`.

Install one, or fix your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need bleeding-edge, don't build it yourself, but use an RPM from [Michael Perzl](http://www.perzl.org/aix/). Right now it goes up to redis 2.6.7.

If you are experienced in building from source, and don't mind altering some source code here and there, read Michael Perzls instructions. Compiling on AIX is not for the faint of heart.

If you want to save yourself a lot of white hairs and headaches, just buy a linux server and set up a good network connection.

Hope this helps, TW